# Help with a query count with multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm not great with sql and I've tried this a lot of different ways and can't come up with a reliable solution.
Basically I have
[image]

I need a query that will tell how many unique instances of *nid* show up for a combination of *tid*.  Basically count with two or more conditionals and only return the number of rows that met all of the conditions. The combination of *tid* s can be more than 2 or more numbers...this will obviously require adding to the query and this is fine (I dont expect a query that accepts an array if that makes sense)...I just need the logic of the query sound.

I need to be able to pass the *tid* 's of 35 & 45 and receive back "2" meaning two complete matches.  The *tid* 35 & 45 both appear with *nid* 4 & 10, but since *tid* 45 doesn't appear in *nid* 2, it should not count it.  I hope that makes sense.

When testing against:

26,27 it should reply "2"

35,27 should reply "2"

31,35 should reply "1"

26,27,45 should reply "1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing the `nid`: `4 and 10`

```
SELECT nid
FROM taxonomy_index
WHERE tid IN (35,45)               --- list of tid to check
GROUP BY nid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tid) = 2     --- count of numbers in list
```

Counting them:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  ( SELECT nid
    FROM taxonomy_index
    WHERE tid IN (35,45)
    GROUP BY nid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tid) = 2
  ) AS grp
```

If the combination `(nid,tid)` is unique, then the `COUNT(DISTINCT tid)` can be replaced with `COUNT(*)`.

Another way is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nid)
FROM taxonomy_index a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM taxonomy_index b
        WHERE b.tid IN (35,45)
          AND NOT EXISTS
              ( SELECT *
                FROM taxonomy_index c
                WHERE c.tid = b.tid
                  AND c.nid = a.nid
              )
      )
```

Comment: If I take that second query and adjust `COUNT(DISTINCT tid) = #tids looking for` then it absolutely works.  For example: `WHERE tid IN (26,27,45)
    GROUP BY nid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tid) = 3` returns "1" like it should.